# Canvas colors works on chrome, not on Safari

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

My canvas rendering show the correct colors on chrome, but just black shapes on safari and mobile browsers.

Here is how I structure my fill string:

`` let fillStr = `rgb(${fill.r * 256},${fill.g * 256},${fill.b * 256})`; ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question, the resulting fill colors will be a float (xx.xx...)
Safari does not honor floats in the fill color.

We should instead convert the numbers to Ints with eg:

`` let fillStr = `rgb(${Math.floor(fill.r * 256)},${Math.floor(fill.g * 256)},${Math.floor(fill.b * 256)})`; ``

Comment: Question was, if I could answer it myself, is it worth posting:
I think so. I searched for over a week for an answer or similar issue. None to be found. I'm hoping this will save someone going through the same time and effort.

Comment: Just one nit: if the r/g/b range is [0,1] then the maximum value should be x255 instead of x256 as 8-bit only covers values [0, 255].

Comment: @epistemex Yes that's important to note. My Upstream provider opted for (0,1), that's why I have 256. I assume they did it to 1) Avoid division by zero (mapping from int to float) and 2) simplify the calculations (keep upper and lower case the same)